# getTextBounds returns different values in design

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw

I'm having a mare with the getTextBounds function when drawing text on a custom view.
When in design mode, the top value is always 0 and bottom has some positive value. When running the app, the values are totally different (example: top=0 bottom=58 becomes top=-37 bottom=7).
Here's the code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    this.paint.getTextBounds("0,", 0, 2, this.bounds);
    int y = 10 + bounds.height();
    canvas.drawText("t=" + bounds.top + " b=" + bounds.bottom, 10, y, this.paint);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are using a different text font on your device ?

Comment: No it's the same font.

Comment: Which version of the SDK and SDT plugin are you using ?